# What Best Practise MVC Security Intranet Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security

need guidance from the mvc master.we are plan to migrate applications mvc 4
for our company's internal purposes. 
Our previous build of VB6 applications with security scheme as follows

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Table Company
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    CompanyID,CompanyName
    -----------------------------
    A         HeadQuarter
    B         Branch 

++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Table User
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    User ID,User Name,CompanyID,Password
    --------------------------------
    John,John Smith,A,XXX!2333333333*
    Rick,Rick Mayer,B,XXX!2333335333*

++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Table Screen
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ScreenID,Screen Name,Type,Module
    --------------------------------
    ACC-01,Setup Account,Screen,Accounting
    ACC-02,Ledger,Screen,Accounting

++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Table AccessRights
++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    ScreenID,UserID,UpdateRights,DeleteRights,AccessLevel
    -----------------------------------------------------
    ACC-01,John,1,1,Null (All Company Data)        
    ACC-01,Rick,1,1,B (Branch Only )
```

and the questions are:

1. What's the best scheme mvc security for the scenario above, if using a custom    membership extended (is there a tutorial on this)
2. how about Access rights implementation in each input screen ? for example  delete button always on in grid data when the user has permissions to delete the data.
3. how the implementation of access rights above in the controller or action?
4. should we make controller per screen related to above design ?

thank you very much for the any help and guidance

Answer (score 0):

I think your case is the perfect example of RBAC Approach. which is already asked in another thread. Here's the Link: [Role Base Access Control Approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536977/simple-yet-dynamic-mvc-authentication-role-bases-access)